# Application not starting when keeping layout xml files in layout-xlarge-land folder

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating an application targeting the tablet users that only in landscape mode. So I created a folder in `res` named as `layout-xlarge-land` and put all my `layout xml` files inside it and kept the `layout folder` empty. I also set the support screen attributes in manifest file

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:smallScreens="false" />
```

I also set all the activity's orientation to landscape

```
activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
```

when I start my application it doesn't starts displaying a stopped unexpectedly message.

But when  I put all the `layout xml` files in `layout folder` my application runs fine.

why this type of behavior? In my view `Android system` should first look into the  `layout-xlarge-land`folder to get the UI. If not found then look into 'layout folder'.
Can someone explain me whether I am right or wrong ?

Logcat:

```
08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to    
start activity ComponentInfo{com.abs.qpr/com.abs.qpr.LauncherActivity}: 

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1751)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1767)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1005)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at    
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468): Caused by: 
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1014)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2039)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:853)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:389)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:245)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1780)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
com.abs.qpr.LauncherActivity.onCreate(LauncherActivity.java:17)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1715)

08-29 12:06:15.040: E/AndroidRuntime(3468):     ... 11 more`
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat error ?

Comment: API level - 8 2.2(Froyo)

Comment: xlarge was introduced in API level 9. So you must specify API 9 in minSdkVersion

Comment: @ChiragRaval  changed the API level to 9 but still not able to run the application. I have added the Logcat details  in my question

Comment: Just Clean project and run again

Comment: @ChiragRaval  I have done that but no affect

Comment: Can anyone help why Android system is not able to find my layouts kept in `layout-xlarge-land` folder.

Comment: Change your project build target to android 2.3 (Means Api 9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. You have to keep at least one i.e, `layout xml` file attached to your `Launcher Activity` inside the `layout` folder rest of the `layout xml` files can be kept inside the `layout-xlarge-land` folder.

Answer (score 1):

As other user mentioned `layout-xlarge-land` is supported API level above 9. Along with changing in manifest, you also have to set build target to 2.3 I guess.

Project -> properties -> android -> change target to 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding this.

```
android:xlargeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true"
```

Comment: and android:xlargeScreens="true"?

Comment: I am getting this error: `No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
          android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
          android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
          android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
          android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>



 check this link once
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Answer (score 0):

As you have `layout-xlarge-land` you also should state that you support `xlarge` screens, not just `large` ones. So add `android:largeScreens="true"` to your `<supports-screens>`.

Comment: I added `android:xlargeScreens="true"` but still getting the same exception.